# Angular child routes reload parent component each time child is called

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I have problem with angular routes, when I navigate to child route the parent is updated again.

I separated the code to 2 main router-outlet:

1. show the login page
2. show all other main pages.

I have the following structure:

**app.module.ts**

imports AppRoutingModule and MainModule

**app.routing.module.ts**

Has the following routes

```
const AppRouting: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**main.module.ts**

imports MainRoutingModule

**main.routing.module.ts**

```
const MainRouting: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'prefix' },
        { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
            data: { permission: { only: ['ALL_APP_ACTIONS', 'ALL_DASHBOARD_ACTIONS', 'DASHBOARD_VIEW'] } }
        },
        { path: 'documents', component: DocumentsComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
            data: { permission: { only: ['ALL_APP_ACTIONS', 'ALL_DOCUMENTS_ACTIONS', 'DOCUMENTS_VIEW'] } }
        }
     ]
   }
]
```

main.component.html

```
<div class="app-wrapper">

<lc-header></lc-header>
<div class="main {{leftMenuActive}}">
    <lc-left-menu (doToggle)="doToggleSideBar()"></lc-left-menu>
    <div class="app-main {{ currentRoutePath }}">
        <div class="app-main-content">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<lc-footer></lc-footer>
</div>
```

So when I'm moving from welcome page to dashboard the parent and left bar are also refreshed.

Can someone help with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your routes are looking ok, so far. Could you please provide some code about how you are calling the router.

Comment: @SebastianMünster thanks for helping, I'm calling like this: <a [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">dashboard</a>

Comment: Can you try to provide a name to the main component's <router-outlet> and use the name in the routing section?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that with no success.
I think maybe the problem is that I have more routing with children. so it is more then 2 levels. But I do not know how to solve this

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this. I am facing same issue. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Israel, did you find any solution to this problem? I am having a similar implementation and facing the same issue. Thanks